# Typescript generics in generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I would like to use generic variable in another generic. Is it possible in current TS?
In example below, the second map method works fine, but I would like to use the first map method implementation ... somehow.

```
type LamdaFn<Value, Result> = (x: Value) => Result;

type None = {
    // desired generic syntax:
    map: <Result> LamdaFn<LamdaFn<null,Result>, None>,
    // currently working but concrete syntax:
    map: <Result>(fn: LamdaFn<null,Result>) => None 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean higher kinded types? They are not supported in TS.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @JonasWilms He is trying to use `<Result> LamdaFn<LamdaFn<null,Result>, None>` as a type - without using function syntax

Comment: @Bergi What is the behaviour of the desired type? It isn't clear.

Comment: @Mack To work exactly like an alias for `<Result>(fn: LamdaFn<null,Result>) => None`.

Comment: Exactly as @Bergi said, so is there any way to do this? 
+ I dont want to provide any further context as I think it does not matter here and I don't want to use any workarounds. Just wonder if it is possible in current TS state
Btw how can I upvote a comment here?

Comment: In short, no it is not possible. You have already seen that the language won't let you do this. With more context, someone can suggest a workaround, but the exact thing you're asking for is not possible.

Comment: @Mack ok thanks, I though that there may be some syntax trick that I missed in the TS docs. Thanks!